Local Quadratic Regression with locfit(): Choose the optimal nearest neighbor
I am running a local quadratic regression with locfit in R. By default, it seems to select adaptive bandwidth with nn=0.7, meaning that 70% of the nearest neighbor variables must be included around the point to compute the smoothing (I guess?).
From simulation results, this actually provides me (by far) the best fit of my model. However, I have no concrete way to justify using this instead of, for example, leave-one-out cross-validation bandwidth or any other plug-in methods (which typically gives me horrible results, completely undersmoothed OR the opposite, very oversmoothed). I have very large dataset, but smooth underlying function, which may explain the problems of the default bandwidth methods.
My problem is that I need to justify this choice of 70% nearest neighbor smoothing parameter when applying it to real data, and it seems quite arbitrary... Is there a paper that justify this choice of nearest neighbor proportion? If not, is there a way to find the "optimal" nn parameter?
I also plan to do bootstrap involving these local quadratic regression. The problem is that the adaptive bandwidth will vary with every bootstrap iteration then. Is this okay? If not, how to specify the same bandwidth as the adaptive bandwidth originally estimated to all the other subsamples? I found how to apply a constant bandwidth, but I did not find how to apply varying adaptive bandwidth to a fix grid of x.
